# convert an array to multi dimensional C without using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

First of all, I would like to know if its possible. If so, please checkout my code and tell me what is wrong.

```
int m[n]; // this is where I pass the values to a array
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { 
    scanf("%d",&a);
    m[i]=a;

}

int v[n][b]; // this is where I pass the values from a array to a 2d array
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { // but for some reason it doesnt work
        for(int j=0;j<b;j++) {
                v[i][j]=m[i];
            }
        }
}
```

The output is :
something like this

```
v[0][0]:0
v[0][1]:0
v[1][0]:1
v[1][1]:1
....
```

but I want something like this:

```
 v[0][0]:0
 v[0][1]:1
 v[1][0]:2
 v[1][1]:3
```

without repeating the values

P.S- if I need to use pointers you can also explain me that way but I would prefer the first one.

Comment: Your 2D array has more elements than your 1D array. How do you plan to fill out the remainder?

Comment: You keep copying `m[i]` to each entry of `v[i][j]` (for each value of `j`), so you're bound to see the same value in each row.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what do you suggest so?

Comment: @merlin2011 I was thinking in putting something like this v[n/b][b] because makes sense to my problem.

Comment: I don't know what to suggest because I don't know what result you want.  All I know is that you don't want the result you get — so you need to change the code.  What result do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In assigning to `v[i][j]`, you are constantly reassigning whatever value was in `m[i]`.

Instead try:

```
v[i][j] = m[i*n + j];
```

This is only going to work if the array `m` has `n*b` elements.

`i*n` represents the row you're working on, and `j` is the column.  Or vice-versa, it's up to you how you imagine it.

Comment: I don't have points enoughts but you're the correct answer! When I have it, I up vote to you

Comment: @ToshiYuki I think you can just accept the answer as correct-preferred. You don't need points for this I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int m[6]; // this is where I pass the values to a array
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int a;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++) { 
        scanf("%d",&a);
        m[i]=a;
    }

    k=0;
    int v[2][3]; // this is where I pass the values from a array to a 2d array
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) { // but for some reason it doesnt work
        for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
            v[i][j]=m[3*k+j]; // 3 is the maximum i value [n of your code]
        }
        k++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Just used OP's code and changed:

1) Defined all integer variables.

2) the `int` inside the for removed to be compatible code with every c compiler (OP doesn't really need this changes)

3) Added a variable `k` that been increased with the changes of outer loop variable and used it in the command  `v[i][j]=m[3*k+j];` to give the appropriate m value to the new array. (3 been explained in the comment of the same line)
**See @Pablo's comment for not using k**

Comment: You don't need the variable `k`, has the same value as `i`, you can do `v[i][j]=m[3*i+j];`

Comment: @Pablo you are right... I don't really know why I used that... Thought somehow complicated that moment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have at least as many elements in your 1D array as your 2D array and you want to fill in your 2D array in row major order, it suffices to just increment an index for your 1D array every time you read an element from it.

```
int v[n][b];
int k = 0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
   for(int j=0;j<b;j++) {
       v[i][j]=m[k++];
   }
}
```